# Connect Sharepoint online using C# with certificate based authentication (CBA)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, certificate, sharepoint-online, azure-app-registration

I am trying to connect to SharePoint Online using c# application. I created a App Registration under Azure Active Directory and added the certification. I have also tested the connection using Powershell(using PnP module) with client, tenant, Cert Thumbprint details and able to connect to SharePoint Online.

Now, I am trying to achieve the same thing using a C# console app(.Net Framework 4.8) but could not find much documention over internet. Could someone please share any C# sample code or refer me to any documention helping me doing this?

Comment: I need an answer to this exact question. Can this be re-opened or OP did you resolve the issue. Please help thank you.

Comment: facing same issue, any advice?

Comment: Install the PNP nuget and create the AuthenticationManager object using one of it's constructor by passing clientID,x509 cert and tenantId. The cert needs to be installed in server and x509 cert object can be created using the cert thumbprint.